# Prove that the convergence of the sum of its coefficients implies the convergence of the Dirichlet series

Tags: convergence-divergence, dirichlet-series

Suppose $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)$ converges to a constant $A$, then prove that the Dirichlet series with coefficients $f(n)$ also converges if $\sigma>0$.

This can be proved easily if the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)$ converges absolutely. However, I have no clue about how to prove this if the series only converges. I tried to fit this series to Cauchy's condition: for every $\varepsilon>0$ we claim that there exists a $p$ such that
$$\left|\frac{f(n)}{n^s}+\cdots+\frac{f(n+p)}{(n+p)^{s}}\right|<\varepsilon$$
But this still requires the series of $f(n)$ to converge absolutely. So how can I approach this? This is Exercise 2 of Chapter 11 in *Introduction to Number Theory* by Apostol.

Comment: *This is a minor part of Exercise 2 of Chapter 11 in Introduction to Number Theory by Apostol.

Comment: Apply Dirichlet test: https://www.britannica.com/science/Dirichlets-test

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy but doesn't that require either $f(n)$ or $1/n^s$ to be real and monotonic?

Comment: @Kavi It is not true that the Dirichlet series is absolute convergent in the OP circumstances (see the eta function and any $1>\sigma_0 >0$, so if we take $f(n)=(-1)^nn^{-\sigma_0+it_0}$ for some fixed $t_0$ so we can make it complex not necessarily real, and we get convergence for any $\sigma>0$ but absolute convergence only for $\sigma > \sigma_0+1$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One proves that convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)$ implies uniform convergence for $\sigma > 0, |\arg s| \le \alpha < \frac{\pi}{2}, s=\sigma+it$ while absolute convergence follows in general only for $\sigma > 1$.

Since for any $s, \Re s >0$ we can find an alpha (depending on $\Im s$ in general) as above, we get the required convergence

The proof is standard and uses that

$|n^{-s}-m^{-s}|=|\int_{\log m}^{\log n}se^{-sx}dx| \le |s||\int_{\log m}^{\log n}e^{-\sigma x}dx|=\frac{|s|}{\sigma}(m^{-\sigma}-n^{-\sigma})$ where $n \ge m \ge 1, s=\sigma+it, \sigma >0$

So as long as $|\frac{|s|}{\sigma}|=|\frac{1}{\cos \arg s}| \le c$ we can apply summation by parts to show that the Cauchy sums $\sum_{m}^{n}f(n)n^{-s} \to 0, n \ge m \to \infty$ and we actually have uniform convergence to zero as long as $c$ is fixed, or if you want $|\cos \arg s| \ge \delta >0$ fixed, which is precisely the angle condition $|\arg s| \le \alpha < \frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: This is a wonderful answer.

Comment: happy to be of help